# Starry sky in Cycles not temporally continual

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

I'm trying to create a starry sky in Cycles using a very simple node setup (Noise texture to ColorRamp). The problem is with animation, the way that light is calculated means that any movement in the camera seems to randomize the star pattern in the sky. From my understanding of how light is calculated in Cycles, light rays are shot out from each pixel a certain number of times, which is the sample count. Based on this, the best reason I can think of for the random stars is that the light paths are randomly either hitting points on the shader where there are stars, or they don't hit that spot, so there is no continuity in star position. Is there an easy way to fix this?

I'm including the file that has a render at 2048 samples of the world. The camera is moving from the azimuth to the zenith and nowhere else: https://ufile.io/j8ttvww4
As you can see, the star movement seems random. The stars are also pretty faint so you might have to turn up your monitor brightness.

The .blend file is also here:
[image]

Comment: Maybe try to switch off the Denoise option?

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos yeah sorry about that, I wasn't sure if it was permanently closed or if someone would come along and reopen, but I waited for a decent amount of time.

Comment: @moonbots I tried with both denoise on and off and it didn't really change anything, plus I would like to not use a ridiculously high sample count. I think it didn't change anything because the way the light was calculated never changed, just the denoise on top of it.

Comment: it may just have to do with the fact that your stars are very small (size of a pixel) and when the camera moves it sometimes makes this pixel disappear